# C++ Derived Classes calling Functions

Tags: c++, derived-class

If I have a derived class in a .cpp file how do I declare before hand? My derived class is encyclopedia but when I want to run a void I type void Encyclopedia::NameofVoid(), but then I get an error. I've tried a lot of combinations of thing but none seem to work. void Book::Encyclopedia::NameofVoid() also doesn't work as shown in th error message.

Encuclopedia.h

```
#ifndef ENCYCLOPEDIAH
#define ENCYCLOPEDIAH

#include "Book.h"

#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Encyclopedia : public Book {
   
   public:

   void SetEdition(string userEdition);
   
   string GetEdition;

   
   void SetNumVolumes(int uesrNumVolumes);
   
   int GetNumVolumes;

   void PrintInfo();

   protected:

   string edition;
   string numVolumes;

};

#endif
```

Encyclopedia.cpp

```
#include "Encyclopedia.h"
#include <iostream>

// Define functions declared in Encyclopedia.h

void Book::Encyclopedia::SetEdition(string userEdition) {
   edition = userEdition;
}

string Encyclopedia::GetEdition() {
   return edition;
}

void Encyclopedia::SetNumVolumes(string userNumVolumes) {
   numVolumes = userNumVolumes;
}

int Encyclopedia::GetNumVolumes() {
   return numVolumes;
}

void Enyclopedia::PrintInfo(){
   cout << "Book Information: " << endl;
   cout << "   Book Title: " << title << endl;
   cout << "   Author: " << author << endl;
   cout << "   Publisher: " << publisher << endl;
   cout << "   Publication Date: " << publicationDate << endl;
   cout << "   Edition: " << edition << endl;
   cout << "   Number of Volumes: " << numVolumes << endl;
}
```

Error:

```
Encyclopedia.cpp:6:12: error: ‘Book::Encyclopedia’ has not been declared
    6 | void Book::Encyclopedia::SetEdition(string userEdition) {
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~~~
Encyclopedia.cpp: In function ‘void SetEdition(std::string)’:
Encyclopedia.cpp:7:4: error: ‘edition’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘SetEdition’?
    7 |    edition = userEdition;
      |    ^~~~~~~
      |    SetEdition
Encyclopedia.cpp: At global scope:
Encyclopedia.cpp:10:8: error: no declaration matches ‘std::string Encyclopedia::GetEdition()’
   10 | string Encyclopedia::GetEdition() {
      |        ^~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from Encyclopedia.cpp:1:
Encyclopedia.h:17:11: note: candidate is: ‘std::string Encyclopedia::GetEdition’
   17 |    string GetEdition;
      |           ^~~~~~~~~~
Encyclopedia.h:10:7: note: ‘class Encyclopedia’ defined here
   10 | class Encyclopedia : public Book {
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~
Encyclopedia.cpp:14:6: error: no declaration matches ‘void Encyclopedia::SetNumVolumes(std::string)’
   14 | void Encyclopedia::SetNumVolumes(string userNumVolumes) {
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from Encyclopedia.cpp:1:
Encyclopedia.h:20:9: note: candidate is: ‘void Encyclopedia::SetNumVolumes(int)’
   20 |    void SetNumVolumes(int uesrNumVolumes);
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
Encyclopedia.h:10:7: note: ‘class Encyclopedia’ defined here
   10 | class Encyclopedia : public Book {
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~
Encyclopedia.cpp:18:5: error: no declaration matches ‘int Encyclopedia::GetNumVolumes()’
   18 | int Encyclopedia::GetNumVolumes() {
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from Encyclopedia.cpp:1:
Encyclopedia.h:22:8: note: candidate is: ‘int Encyclopedia::GetNumVolumes’
   22 |    int GetNumVolumes;
      |        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
Encyclopedia.h:10:7: note: ‘class Encyclopedia’ defined here
   10 | class Encyclopedia : public Book {
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~
Encyclopedia.cpp:22:6: error: ‘Enyclopedia’ has not been declared
   22 | void Enyclopedia::PrintInfo(){
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~
Encyclopedia.cpp: In function ‘void PrintInfo()’:
Encyclopedia.cpp:24:33: error: ‘title’ was not declared in this scope
   24 |    cout << "   Book Title: " << title << endl;
      |                                 ^~~~~
Encyclopedia.cpp:25:29: error: ‘author’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘auto’?
   25 |    cout << "   Author: " << author << endl;
      |                             ^~~~~~
      |                             auto
Encyclopedia.cpp:26:32: error: ‘publisher’ was not declared in this scope
   26 |    cout << "   Publisher: " << publisher << endl;
      |                                ^~~~~~~~~
Encyclopedia.cpp:27:39: error: ‘publicationDate’ was not declared in this scope
   27 |    cout << "   Publication Date: " << publicationDate << endl;
      |                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Encyclopedia.cpp:28:30: error: ‘edition’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘SetEdition’?
   28 |    cout << "   Edition: " << edition << endl;
      |                              ^~~~~~~
      |                              SetEdition
Encyclopedia.cpp:29:40: error: ‘numVolumes’ was not declared in this scope
   29 |    cout << "   Number of Volumes: " << numVolumes << endl;
      |                                        ^~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: What do you mean by running void ? Can you print error message here ?

Comment: Is Book a namespace you have declared? If yes, you need to define functions like : void Book::Encyclopedia::NameofVoid()

Comment: Please add the content of ```Encyclopedia.h``` to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first error is the one you want to look at:

> error: ‘Book::Encyclopedia’ has not been declared

It is telling you that it cant find the type `Book::Encyclopedia`. Which is true, you have `Book` and `Encyclopedia` as distinct classes. `Book::Encyclopedia` would be declared like:

```
class Book {
    class Encyclopedia {
```

Since your function `SetEdition` is being defined for `Encyclopedia` you only need this:

```
void Encyclopedia::SetEdition(string userEdition) {
   edition = userEdition;
}
```

Just like the other functions you have below it.

Comment: @KatieOsadczuk Yes, but did you read what they say? `no declaration matches ‘std::string Encyclopedia::GetEdition()` - because you haven't declared a `std::string GetEdition();` member function, you've declared a `std::string GetEdition;` member **variable**.